# combo box ValueChanged event affecting two cbos

Tags: c#, epicorerp

I'm new to C# so I may be going about this all wrong.  I have two combo boxes.  When one has a value the other should always be string.Empty.  My problem is once I change the value in one I set other to string.Empty.  Which, of course, fires that event and sets the control I changed to string.Empty.  So I always have to enter the value twice.  I've tried several if statements to keep this from happening but nothing has worked. I'm using ValueChanged.  Should I be using some other event?

```
private static void cboJobDetailer_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    // ** Place Event Handling Code Here **
    if (cboJobDetailer.Value != string.Empty) {
        var edvJobPart = (EpiDataView)oTrans.EpiDataViews["JobPart"];
        edvJobPart.dataView[edvJobPart.Row]["BI_JobOutsourceID_c"] = string.Empty;
        cboOutsourceCo.Value = string.Empty;
    }
}

private static void cboOutsourceCo_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    // ** Place Event Handling Code Here **
    if (cboOutsourceCo.Value != string.Empty){
        var edvJobPart = (EpiDataView)oTrans.EpiDataViews["JobPart"];
        edvJobPart.dataView[edvJobPart.Row]["BI_JobDetailerID_c"] = string.Empty;
        cboJobDetailer.Value = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

In Epicor ERP the combo box is a Ice.Lib.Framework.EpiUltraCombo, this inherits from an Infragistics UltraCombo which implements the ValueChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

While standard .Net WinForms use the control events, Epicor ERP is designed to respond to data change events, such as `JobPart_Column.ColumnChanged`. This DataTable would be defined for you in a UI customisation script.

In any case to prevent events firing off each other, set a module level flag while you are changing data in code. Then test this in your events, the event will still fire but won't do anything.

```
bool dataChangingInCode = false;

    public void InitializeCustomCode()
    {
        JobPart_Column.ColumnChanged += JobPart_ColumnChanged;
    }

    private void JobPart_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataChangingInCode) return;

        switch (e.Column.ColumnName)
        {
            case "BI_JobDetailerID_c":
                dataChangingInCode = true;
                e.Row["BI_JobOutsourceID_c"] = string.Empty;
                dataChangingInCode = false;
                break;
            case "BI_JobOutsourceID_c":
                dataChangingInCode = true;
                e.Row["BI_JobDetailerID_c"] = string.Empty;
                dataChangingInCode = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Web.  I'll have to modify this to work with a static class (yes, I used the code generator) or else modify my existing class so it is no longer static.  I can see I need to spend more time with C# so I don't have to use the code generator.